# How to visually differentiate between manual and automatic edit capabilities

Tags: website-design, icon, information-design, information-architecture

I'm having some difficulty find an icon or solution to differentiate operation in the same table, but with different origin.

In my table I have operation imported from a central system and others created manually by the user. The ones imported are partial editable, the manually created are fully editable.

I need to add some visual information and a tooltip to help the user differentiate each one.

I've tried this icon [image]

But Isn't ok, this seems that only that row is editable, but the others are also editable, but only partial.

[image: mockup]

Comment: Disagree that this question is about an icon, an icon was just one of the solutions OP tried.

Comment: Does the user know the difference between manual and automatic registration? ie manual = fully editable, automatic = partial editable

Comment: This should be migrated back to UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give visual hints about what the user can edit directly in the content.

[image: Example]

Here, the third row was manually created (shown by icon), so all it's fields can be edited. The other rows stem from the system, but we can still always edit the third entry.

This can be further reinforced through hover effects and tool-tips.

Comment: This is the current aspect of the GUI, I've added the information icon with a tooltip.

![enter image description here][1]

@Lukzen Your suggestion to use visual hints in the editable content will also work as reinforcement.

Thanks

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHnbt.png